# Are ruby strings that return true for #ascii_only? a subset of strings that return true for Activesupport's #is_utf8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

I have a requirement to determine if a very large number of characters of unknown encoding are utf8. I'm using ActiveSupport *#is_utf8?*, however it is quite slow because it duplicates the string. I am wondering if I can put a guard clause using *#ascii_only*. My testing show that this will improve the performance of my utf8? method.

Original method:

```
def utf8? character
  character.is_utf8?
end
```

Faster method:

```
def utf8? character
  return true if character.ascii_only?
  character.is_utf8?
end
```

**Is there a character that will return false for ActiveSupport's *String#is_utf8?* that will return true for *String#ascii_only*?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a character that will return false for ActiveSupport's String#is_utf8? 
>   [and] true for String#ascii_only?

According to the definition of UTF-8, there is no such character.

> The first 128 characters of Unicode .. correspond one-to-one with ASCII
>   (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

But, do these functions respect this definition? Yes, they do. :)

`ascii_only?` returns true **only for characters `0..127`**, regardless of which encoding we specify.

```
127.chr(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT).ascii_only? #=> true
128.chr(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT).ascii_only? #=> false
127.chr(Encoding::UTF_8).ascii_only? #=> true
128.chr(Encoding::UTF_8).ascii_only? #=> false
```

Now let's look at `is_utf8?`. To answer our question, we only need to consider characters `0..127`.

```
(0..127).any? { |i| !i.chr(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT).is_utf8? }
#=> false
```

In the range `0..127`, there are no characters for which `is_utf8?` returns false.

Comment: Interesting side-note, the `mail` gem monkey-patches `String#ascii_only?`. See `/mail/core_extensions/string.rb`. So, if you use that gem, that's a different question that I didn't look into.